# Spring Tool Suite 3.3.0 - Build Path is Incomplete (but it is not)

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

I get these constant error message (red cross) on my beans in my root-context.xml file saying that the "Build Path is Incomplete".  If I press the space bar and save the file the error messages disappear.

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: Did you validate the context file?

Comment: yeah, as I say everything works fine. All i need to do is modify the file and save it and the error goes away...until the next build where it might come back

Comment: It looks like the spring builder isn't being invoked at the correct times.  First, make sure you have "build automatically" enabled.  Also, make sure that your project has the Spring builder installed.  Lastly, check your error log for relevant errors.

Comment: I have stopped getting this error now but I don't know the exact point when the error stopped occurring.  It may have been an update to the latest version of STS (3.4.0) or due to some maven project refactoring.